# IF controller (radio button/counter) and Loop Controller in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'd like to practice IF controller basically as follow:

TEST_PLAN

+Thread_group: (user: 3, ramp: 3, loop:2)

+Loop_Controller(loop:4)

++ HTTP request1: go to page_1

+IF_Controller1

++ HTTP request2: go to page_2

++ counter (config element)

+IF_Controller2

++ HTTP request3: click Back button

My condition "HTTP request 2" is only executed if loop (output "Loop_Controller" >4). How to do that ? 
And, for IF_Controller2: it's will be executed after each of question on this page has checked (page has 5 questions, 1 question has 5 answer radio button.)

I also follow the Counter element and Counter functions, but don't know how to combine them?

and one more things: to use the variable in IF statement, they should be put on previous activities ? (in my case: IF controller: ${count}, thereby variable "count" should be put on HTTP request 1)

Thanks,

Comment: There is already a loop count of 2 in the Thread Group. Then why are you adding a loop counter? And what exactly are you trying to do with the IF condition?

Comment: Because I think the loop in thread group will loop the request, and Counter(config element) is just a counter to "count". Then, I put this "count" to IF controller (or While Controller) to make condition.

Comment: Can you give me a bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve? Or are you just playing around jmeter trying to learn?

Comment: Because my local web is stopped due to network. Let get others to explain. The page I'm testing is [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). HTTP request_1 is go to [Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual) if loop > 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place COUNTER as a child of **Loop Controller**, not If Controller. In this case you'll get the following scenario:

```
HTTP Request 1 (loop 1)
HTTP Request 1 (loop 2)
HTTP Request 1 (loop 3)
HTTP Request 1 (loop 4)
** HERE we're getting out of Loop Controller and go to 2nd Loop of Thread Group, If controller doesn't fire as counter value is 4 and condition is >4**
HTTP Request 1 (loop 5)
HTTP Request 1 (loop 6)
HTTP Request 1 (loop 7)
HTTP Request 1 (loop 8)
** HERE counter value is 8 and If controller condition is met so **
HTTP Request 2
```

Being child of If Controller counter **isn't getting incremented**

Counter Configuration:

- Start: 1
- Increment: 1
- Reference Name: N

If Controller Configuration:

```
${N} > 4
```

See [How to use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) guide for more details.

Comment: Does have relationship between Loop in Thread and the Counter(config element) ? would you please explain for me. In case, I use While Controller, can I use Counter (config element) into it, and can i use While Controller replace for LOOP+IF Controller ?

Comment: Counter is getting incremented any time it occurs. 1 loop = 1 increment, no matter what what the loop cause. I don't fully understand your use case to give advice. While controller will be running till `condition` becomes `false`.Loop controller will be running specified number of loops so they are different.